# Locking/Manager incapsulation with python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, locks

This following simplified example fails with an exception called

```
AttributeError: type object 'SyncManager' has no attribute 'from_address'
```

Example code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class Inserter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cache = {}
        self.manager = mp.Manager()
        self.lock = self.manager.Lock()                   

    def __call__(self, filename):
        with self.lock:
            print filename

if __name__ == "__main__":
    files = [
        {'a':1, 'b':2},
        {'b':1, 'c':2},
        {'d':1, 'e':2},
        {'b':1, 'd':2},
    ]

    inserter = Inserter()
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=None)
    pool.imap_unordered(inserter, files)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

I wonder how I could incapsulate a manager and locking semantics within the Inserter class (i.e., without explicitly passing lock objects into the callable function)?

Comment: Could you write down an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I already came to a conclusion that you cannot create a callable object, i.e. an instance of a class with __call__ defined, and simultaneously have that instance store multiprocessing.Manager and/or multiprocessing.Lock instance, I am just unsure why. 

What I'm trying to achieve is a class hiding locks/managers inside its object and compatible (in some way) with multiprocessing.Pool so that I don't have to instantiate managers/locks in main.

Comment: @artonson, I am having exactly same issue. Were you able to find a solution for this?